# Completions of a vector space with inner product

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

Assume $(H,(\cdot,\cdot)_H)$, and $(G,(\cdot,\cdot)_G)$ are two vector spaces with inner product. Suppose $A:H\rightarrow G$ is a linear isometry.

Let $T(H)_{*}$ be the completion of $T(H)$ with respect to $(\cdot,\cdot)_G$.

Let $H_{*}$ be the completion of $H$ with respect to $(\cdot,\cdot)_H$.

Question: Is it true that $T(H)_{*}=T(H_{*})$, where $T$ has been extended by continuity to $H_{*}$?

Comment: You're basically asking whether an isometry between dense sets can be extended to a unitary. Answer is yes trivially.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true.

To prove $T(H_*)\subseteq T(H)_*$, you should prove that the image of every Cauchy sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $H$ is a Cauchy sequence in $G$ and the limit of $\{x_n\}$ is mapped to the limit of $\{Tx_n\}$.

To prove $T(H)_*\subseteq T(H_*)$, you should prove that the inverse image of every Cauchy sequence in $G$ is a Cauchy sequence in $H$ whose limit in $H$ is the inverse image of the limit of the former sequence in $G$.

Comment: That might work, yes.

Meantime, another way is to observe that $T(H)\subset T(H_*)$, and since $T$ is an isometry $T(H_*)$ is $(\cdot,\cdot)_G$ complete, showing $T(H)_*\subset T(H_*)$.

The other inclusion follows readily from the definition of the extension of $T$ to the completion $H_*$.